# Connection's issue on cassandra database

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark

i have problems to connect cassandra to spark, i can connect to cassandra by `cqlsh` but when i launch my program:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Cluster cluster;
            Session session;
            cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
            session = cluster.connect();
            SparkConf conf = new SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CassandraExamples").setMaster("local[1]")
            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "9.168.86.84");
            JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("spark://9.168.86.84:9042","CassandraExample",conf);
            CassandraJavaPairRDD<String, String> rdd1 = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("keyspace", "table",
                    mapColumnTo(String.class), mapColumnTo(String.class)).select("row1", "row2");
            System.out.println("Data  fetched: \n" + StringUtils.join(rdd1.toArray(), "\n"));

}
```

i'm getting this error:

```
    15/06/11 11:41:15 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@9.168.86.84:9042]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: Connection refused: no further information: /9.168.86.84:9042
15/06/11 11:41:34 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@9.168.86.84:9042/user/Master...
15/06/11 11:41:35 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@9.168.86.84:9042: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@9.168.86.84:9042
15/06/11 11:41:35 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@9.168.86.84:9042]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: Connection refused: no further information: /9.168.86.84:9042
15/06/11 11:41:54 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@9.168.86.84:9042/user/Master...
15/06/11 11:41:55 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@9.168.86.84:9042: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@9.168.86.84:9042
15/06/11 11:41:55 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@9.168.86.84:9042]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: Connection refused: no further information: /9.168.86.84:9042
15/06/11 11:42:14 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
15/06/11 11:42:14 WARN SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
15/06/11 11:42:14 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
```

cassandra.yaml has this properties:

```
listen_address: 9.168.86.84
start_native_transport: true 
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
native_transport_port: 9042
rpc_port: 9160
```

can someone tell my what's wrong?

Comment: Change the rpc address to 9.168.86.84

Comment: tried, and it's not working.

Comment: try changing `addcontactPoint("9.168.86.84")`

Comment: @Knight71 with your last suggestion, i got this  `All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /9.168.86.84:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/9.168.86.84:9042] `